# After adding new content type, drupal (7) returns to same window without any notification

Tags: 7, nodes

As in the title, every time I add a new content type Drupal returns to the same page and provides no notifications.

Also, the overlay window is full screen width. Any ideas? No error logs.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by adding content type?
It Is normal that drupal return to the front page after creating a new content type...

Do you mean creating a node?Where does drupal returns?